# Issue with String.Split result

Tags: c#

I trying to load 4 lines from text files:

```
email:pass
email1:pass1
email2:pass2
email3:pass3
```

I used string.split, however when I try to Add to the my List it doesn't load well.

Here what I tried:

```
List<string> AccountList = new List<string>();
Console.Write("File Location: ");
string FileLocation = Console.ReadLine();
string[] temp = File.ReadAllLines(FileLocation);
string[] tempNew = new string[1000];

int count = 0;
foreach(var s in temp)
{
    AccountList.Add(s.Split(':').ToString());
    count++;
}
```

I checked how it the strings look inside the lists and they were like this:

```
System.String[]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
AccountList[0] = email
AccountList[1] = pass
AccountList[2] = email1
AccountList[3] = pass1
```

Comment: Please see [the documentation of `String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) and what it actually returns.

Comment: and what is your expected result?

Comment: my expected result is to get
AccountList[0] = email

AccountList[1] = pass

Comment: `List<string> AccountList = File.ReadAllLines(FileLocation).SelectMany(line => line.Split(':')).ToList();`

Comment: Your problem at hand aside, the desired output structure seems a bit clunky - usually you'd want that kind of data as pairs, not subsequent list items. Making `AccountList` a `List<string[]>` would even allow you to directly use the result of `.Split()`.

Comment: Just call `AccountList.AddRange(s.Split(':'));`

Answer (score 5):

`String.Split` yields a string array

```
foreach(var s in temp)
{
    string[] parts = s.Split(':');
    string email = parts[0];
    string pass = parts[1];
    ...
}
```

To store these two pieces of information, create an account [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes):

```
public class Account
{
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then declare your account list as `List<Account>`:

```
var accountList = new List<Account>();
foreach(var s in File.ReadLines(FileLocation))
{
    string[] parts = s.Split(':');
    var account = new Account { EMail = parts[0], Password = parts[1] };
    accountList.Add(account);
}
```

Note that you don't need the `temp` variable. `File.ReadLines` reads the file as the loop progresses, so that the whole file needs not to be stored in memory. See: [File.ReadLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) (Microsoft Docs).

No need to count. You can get the count with

```
int count = accountList.Count;
```

This list will be easier to handle than a list interleaved with emails and passwords.

You can access an account by index

```
string email = accountList[i].EMail;
string pass = accountList[i].Password;
```

or

```
Account account = accountList[i];
Console.WriteLine($"Account = {account.EMail}, Pwd = {account.Password}");
```

Answer (score 1):

From your expected result you can try this, `string.Split` will return a string array `string[]`, which spite by your expect character.

then use the index to get string part.

```
foreach(var s in temp)
{ 
   var arr = s.Split(':');
   AccountList.Add(arr[0]);
   AccountList.Add(arr[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Split` returns a string array consisting of the parts of the string found between the split character(s), and you're treating it as a string.

Instead, your code can be simplified by taking the result of `File.ReadAllLines` (a string array) and using `.SelectMany` to select the resulting array from splitting each line on the `:` character (so you're selecting an array for each item in the array), and then calling `ToList` on the result (since you're storing it in a list).

For example:

```
Console.Write("Enter file location: ");
string fileLocation = Console.ReadLine();

// Ensure the file exists
while (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
{
    Console.Write("File not found, please try again: ");
    fileLocation = Console.ReadLine();
}

// Read all the lines, split on the ':' character, into a list
List<string> accountList = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation)
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(':'))
    .ToList();
```